# NHibernate - Found shared references to a collection

Tags: nhibernate

In my ASP.NET webforms app, I am getting the above exception predominately, along with:
- A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: Persistence.Product.ModelMap
- collection was processed twice by flush()
- Found shared references to a collection: Persistence.Product.ModelMap
when I am retrieving products. It happens only when I have two or more requests hit the server at once. I am using one session per request.

The property, ModelMap, is defined as follows in the Hibernate XML in the Products mapping definition:

```
<bag name="ModelMap" table="MapProductModel" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="true" inverse="true" where="IsDeleted=0">
  <key column="fkProductId" />
  <one-to-many class="MapProductModel" />
</bag>
```

This happens on the following line of code

```
IList<T> itemList = criteria.List<T>();
```

When the retrieving the product.

Any help greatly appreciated, Google didn't really turn up anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET is multithreaded, so requests will come in on multiple threads in the same HTTP request. You should be using NHibernate's web session context (or other means); creating a new session per HTTP request is not enough. See http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/architecture.html#architecture-current-session

Answer (score 1):

criteria.List triggers a session flush which causes NH to go over all your objects and figure out what commands need to be sent to the db.  Any other session flush would probably trigger the same exception.

Something about the way you're working with ModelMap is causing the flush cycle to break.  When I've had these errors I usually narrow it down by commenting out places I reference the collection one by one.  Once you know the offending line fixing it should be easy (hopefully)

Comment: I've fixed it temporarily by using lock around the ISession object. The thing is though, that the session is created on a per-request basis by the session factory so I find it really odd that it's looking like a threading issue when the session should be unique per thread.